# How to Remove "Using Format" on Portfolio

Tags: html, format

How to remove the "using format" hoverlink in the bottom right hand corner of portfolio website?

Website: colinpieters.com

Comment: plz add some more deatails in the question

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell, this can't be 'removed' which seems pretty cheeky for a paid service.

I'd suggest looking at Squarespace as an alternative that provides paid customers with the option to remove badging.

Comment: Cant he just set the font-size to 0?

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove this, please reach out to the customer service team and they will gladly remove it for  you! That's the easy solution until it becomes a function.

Answer (score -1):

Their support team responded that:

> This is possible on a Pro plan or above.

But you can also click "Edit Code" button in Design Editor and override the CSS like this:

```
#using { font-size: 0 !important; }
```